# Rebuild Keras-model in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm new to Tensorflow and I'm trying to rebuild a simple network, that I've built in Keras (TF backend), with Tensorflows Python API. It is a simple function approximator (z = sin(x + y)).

I've tried different architectures, optimizers and learning rates, but I'm not getting the new network to train properly. However in my eyes, the networks seem to be identical. Both get the exact same feature vectors and labels:

```py
# making training data
start = 0
end = 2*np.pi
samp = 1000
num_samp = samp**2
step = end / samp

x_train  = np.arange(start, end, step)
y_train  = np.arange(start, end, step)

data = np.array(np.meshgrid(x_train,y_train)).T.reshape(-1,2)
z_label = np.sin(data[:,0] + data[:,1])
```

Here is the Keras model:

```py
#start model
model = Sequential()

#stack layers
model.add(Dense(units=128, activation='sigmoid', input_dim=2, name='dense_1'))
model.add(Dense(units=64, activation='sigmoid', input_dim=128, name='dense_2'))
model.add(Dense(units=1, activation='linear', name='output'))

#compile model
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',
              optimizer='sgd',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath='./weights/weights.h5',
                               verbose=1, save_best_only=True)

tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir="logs/{}".format(time()))

model.fit(data, z_label, epochs=20, batch_size=32,
          shuffle='true',validation_data=(data_val, z_label_val),
          callbacks=[checkpointer, tensorboard])
```

Here is the new network, built with Tensorflows Python API:

```py
# hyperparameter
n_inputs = 2
n_hidden1 = 128
n_hidden2 = 64
n_outputs = 1
learning_rate = 0.01

# construction phase
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, n_inputs), name='input')
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None), name="target")

hidden1 = tf.layers.dense(X, n_hidden1, name="hidden1", activation=tf.nn.sigmoid)
hidden2 = tf.layers.dense(hidden1, n_hidden2, name="hidden2", activation=tf.nn.sigmoid)
logits = tf.layers.dense(hidden2, n_outputs, activation='linear', name='output')

loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(logits - y),  name='loss')

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate)

training_op = optimizer.minimize(loss, name='train')

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

saver = tf.train.Saver()

# --- execution phase ---
n_epochs = 40
batch_size = 32
n_batches = int(num_samp/batch_size)

with tf.Session() as sess:

    init.run()

    for epoch in range(n_epochs):
        print("Epoch: ", epoch, " Running...")
        loss_arr = np.array([])

        for iteration in range( n_batches ):
            start = iteration * batch_size
            end = start + batch_size

            sess.run(training_op, feed_dict={X: data[start:end], y: z_label[start:end] })
            loss_arr = np.append(loss_arr, loss.eval(feed_dict={X: data[start:end, :], y: z_label[start:end]}))

        mean_loss = np.mean(loss_arr)
        print("Epoch: ", epoch, " Calculated ==> Loss: ", mean_loss)
```

While the Keras model train properly with a decreasing loss and proper test results, the new model converges pretty fast and stops learning. Accordingly the results are completely useless.

Am I building/training the the model incorrectly or is Keras doing anything in the background, that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this issue. The problem was the shape of the label vector. It was a lying vector with shape (1000000,). While Keras is apparently capable of dealing with different shapes of output and label vectors, Tensorflow initialized the placeholder incorrectly and the loss function

```py
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(logits - y),  name='loss')
```

did't make sense anymore and thus training failed. Adding

```py
z_label = z_label.reshape(-1,1)
```

reshaped the label vector to (1000000, 1) and solved it. Alternatively one can specify the shape of the placeholder more precisely

```py
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None,1), name="target")
```